# Newtonsoft.Json - custom deserializer for single-element lists?

Tags: json.net

I have some Json input to deserialize, that has a weird schema. (I can't do anything about the schema.)

Basically all things that should be a string, a number, an object are instead **lists of a single item** of type string, number, object.

Here's an example:

```
{
    "country": [
        "GB"
    ],
    "shippingInfo": [
        {
            "shippingServiceCost": [
                {
                    "@currencyId": "GBP",  //these 2 properties are an exception - not wrapped in lists
                    "__value__": "8.0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "listingInfo": [
        {
            "startTime": [
                "2020-12-05T17:04:21.000Z"
            ],
            "watchCount": [
                "4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like my model class to look like

```
class Model 
{
    public string country { get; set; }  //not List<string>
    //etc
}
```

Can you think of a clean way to deserialize this?

Comment: Is it only *object properties* that are converted to arrays?  What about the root object, or array items?  Are those also wrapped in arrays?

Comment: @dbc I can only see one "actual list" property, and it's not wrapped in an extra array. The root object _is_ wrapped. Objects and *most* simple properties are also wrapped. I was thinking there should be a way to specify a default "wrapped list" converter, and opt-out of it for specific properties where it's not needed. So far I went for an "opt-in" approach which is verbose, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to create a custom converter and sprinkle it to all properties that needed it:

```
class Model 
{
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleItemListConverter))]
    public string Country2LetterCode { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SingleItemListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Not an array: {reader.TokenType} {reader.Value}");
        }
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        var single = array.Single();

        return single?.ToObject(objectType);
    }
        
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
        
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```